# Find the sum and position of the maximum value in a list

Tags: python, list, max

I'd like to create a function that will print the sum and the position of the maximum value within a list of numbers, but I'm not sure how to go about doing so.. This is what I've started with so far:

I used some code off a similar question that was asked.

```
def maxvalpos(variables):
    max = 0 
    for i in range(len(variables)):
        if variables[i] > max:
            max = variables[i]
            maxIndex = i 
    return (max, maxIndex)

print maxvalpos(4, 2, 5, 10)
```

When I run this code it just returns that the function can only take 1 argument. Thank you.

Comment: You'll probably want to return something from `maxvalpos` such as `return (max, maxIndex)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then give it one argument, or modify the definition.

```
print maxvalpos([4, 2, 5, 10])
```

or

```
def maxvalpos(*variables):
```

Comment: When I put the [] brackets in the print statement it now just returns None, do you know why? I'm assuming it's something to do with my code

Comment: You never return anything from your function.

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way of doing this:

```
my_list_sum=sum(my_list)
index_max=my_list.index(max(my_list))
```

This finds the sum of the list and the index of the maximum of the list

But the problem in your code is: You are sending four variables to the function and receiving only 1 variable. For that to work, use:

```
maxvalpos([4,2,7,10])
```

This sends only one argument, a list to the function

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do this

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> maxpos, maxval = max(enumerate(my_list), key=itemgetter(1))
```

eg.

```
>>> max(enumerate([4, 2, 5, 10]), key=itemgetter(1))
(3, 10)
```